# jquery: Modal is always in the bottom left and behind overlay, how can I fix this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Okay, so right now every time I call a function that opens a modal, and the modal is always behind the overlay, and also always in the bottom left. No matter what I change around it never moves. I was under the assumption that by default modals are centered.

Here is my jquery:

```
$('#container').dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        position: 'center',
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                            $("#content").load('<%= Url.Action("Action") %>');
                        },
                        buttons: {
                            "Close": function() {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I center my modal(or at least take it away from the bottom left), and bring it in front of the overlay?

I am using the jQuery UI CSS.

Comment: please show us the appropriate html if there is one and also please clarify the question. what exactly are you asking? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met similar situation before, and I able to center the dialog to the center by assigning a fixed width:

```
 var $detaildialog = $('#tableplaceholder').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Food Details',
            modal: true,
            // Set fixed width for dialog to position center
            width: '800',
            height: 'auto'
        });
```

To let it show above the overlay, perhaps you could try zIndex, or check:

1. The sequence you declare and open your dialog. If you open your dialog after certain action, make sure the sequence is correct. Sometime you do need to declare your dialog **inside** the function for it to work perfectly
2. Is there any other dialog open before this dialog? If yes, try destroy the dialog when it close:

   ```
    close: function () {
               $(this).dialog('destroy');
           }
   ```

   This solve some misbehavior of my dialog

Hope all this will help :)